# How to set initial view options for PDF documents (exporting from MS Word)

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation, doc

Is it possible to change initial view options when exporting in MS Word (2010) to PDF or change it after it is ready.

My specific need is to change Default (which is usually Page) to something like Page and Bookmarks. Ability to change start page would be nice too.

I'm comfortable with changing bits or running some tool from cmd (if it would give stable results).

And yes, I know OpenOffice can do that (when exporting from DOC), but OpenOffice sometimes changes layout of elements...

Answer (score 0):

You can't control these options when creating a PDF from within Word. You should use Adobe Acrobat or something like that. I use PDF Editor (on Ubuntu).

Comment: Any specific PDF Editor? Haven't found any useful and free (or cheap).